# PyPI Packaging: install_requires `pillow`

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-imaging-library

I testing my PyPI package, before upload, with `pip3 install -e .`, in the package directory.

It depends on `pillow` (import PIL in code).

When I tested with already installed pillow it worked.

But, I uninstall the `pillow` then reinstall my package with `pip3 install -e .`, it didn't work:

```
Obtaining file:///Users/hongbook/dev/identicon
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/hongbook/dev/identicon/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        import Identicon
      File "/Users/hongbook/dev/identicon/Identicon/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from .Identicon import render
      File "/Users/hongbook/dev/identicon/Identicon/Identicon.py", line 5, in <module>
        from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

I expected when I install that, `pillow` should be installed since I wrote it `install_requires`'s value in `setup.py`(also that in `requirements.txt`):

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

...

setup(
    name='Identicon',
    version=Identicon.__version__,
    ...
    install_requires=[
        'pillow',  
    ],
)

# requirements.txt
pillow
```

How can I make dependency my project to `pillow` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is stemming from this:

```
version=Identicon.__version__,
```

In order to do that, you're importing `Identicon`, which is your package, which imports `PIL`.  So, your `setup.py` is broken.  It requires the dependencies to be already installed in order to execute, however it's the `setup.py` job to install those dependencies in the first place.

This is a common "chicken and egg" situation in packaging.  The solution is to use a different way to parse the version number from your package, or store the version number somewhere that doesn't trigger imports of your dependencies.

Comment: Got it. But I refer the [howdoi's setup.py](https://github.com/gleitz/howdoi/blob/master/setup.py). How could that possible? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: [Look at their `__init__.py` file](https://github.com/gleitz/howdoi/blob/master/howdoi/__init__.py).  **It doesn't trigger imports of dependencies**.  But in your `__init__.py` file, you do (I can see it in the traceback).

Comment: Yes, removing `import Identicon` in my `__init__.py` works. It solve that problem but on designing project structure still.. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can import version without importing the entire package using `imp`. See how I do it in [SQLObject](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/master/setup.py):

```
from imp import load_source
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

versionpath = join(abspath(dirname(__file__)), "sqlobject", "__version__.py")
sqlobject_version = load_source("sqlobject_version", versionpath)

setup(name="SQLObject",
      version=sqlobject_version.version,
      …
     )
```

Comment: `imp` is deprecated since version 3.4

Comment: Works perfectly in 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6. ;-)

Comment: There are better ways to isolate the version number that don't require these kind of hacks.

Comment: It's rather opinion-based if those ways are really better! ;-)